# showing a filled combobox in modelform that is filtered by a pk

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class LocationType(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   Description=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Location(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100) 
   ParentCode=models.BigIntegerField() 
   LocationType=models.ForeignKey(LocationType)

class Visa(models.Model): 
   Country=models.ForeignKey(Location)
   Price=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   ActionUser=models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
```

In `forms.py` I have this:

```
class VisaForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model=Visa
```

I want to show a combobox of locations(for Country field of Visa model) in visa form that are filtered by a special `LocationType`.

Imagine i have a `LocationType` with value `name=Country,pk=1`. In `visa_form` I want to show a list of `Location`s, but not all of them. Just locations with `locationType_id=1`.

How can I fill this combobox and show it in visa form?

Answer (score 3):

Something on the lines of:

```
class VisaForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, location_type, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VisaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Country'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.filter(LocationType=location_type))

    class Meta:
        model=Visa
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a django ChoiceField. It takes an arg `choices` that you can set to a tuple type (you can make a list to a tuple in the end because you'll probably be starting with a list). You just filter objects based on name=Country, and pk=1, and then `CHOICES` (if you want to name your variable that), and set `choices = CHOICES`.

I hope that helps.

As far as adding the `ChoicesField` to the `ModelForm` you might be able to inherit from it and add the field.

Comment: Perhaps the [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) would be more appropriate for case in question.

Comment: thank U everybodey,I did this and it worked: in __init__ self.fields["Country"].queryset=Location.objects.filter(LocationTypeCode__id=locationType.id)